# Android PWA push notification click opens Chrome Site settings instead of the app

Tags: android, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

We are developing a PWA application for Android. We added notifications and they work fine, as long as the app is running in the background. If a notification is received and the app is not running, clicking on the notification takes the user to the Chrome Site settings for our app (as shown in the attached capture). What we want is the device to open the PWA app and set the internal URL to the one passed with the notification.

To be clear, if the app is running (even in the background) and a notification is clicked, it focuses the app and takes the internal browser to the desired url. The only problem is when the app is not running.

Below is the code from our service worker that treats the onclick notification:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) 
{       
    event.notification.close();

    if(event.notification.data.url)
    {
        var url = event.notification.data.url;    
    
        event.waitUntil(        

            self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true,type: "window"})
            .then((clientList) => {

              if(clientList.length === 0) 
              {
                return self.clients.openWindow(url)
                        .then((windowClient) => {
                    if (windowClient) {
                      windowClient.navigate(url);
                      return windowClient.focus();
                    } 
                    else {
                      return Promise.resolve();
                    }
                });
              }                                  
              
              const client = clientList[0]
              
              return Promise.all([
                client.focus(),
                client.navigate(url)
              ]);             
          })
        );
    }

}, false);
```

[image: Chrome Site settings]

Any idea why it's not working?

Thank you.